# Kmeans implementation in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a code that do kmeans on text data. It has about 160 lines of code. My main goal is to query a database with the data provided by the user and then conduct on these text kmeans.

The table output of the data queried by the user is working. Now I would like to rewrite the code to shiny.

```
# Here is the data that is provided by the query
query <- reactive({
    query <- get_sql_query(input$key)
    query_data <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
  })

  word_extract <- function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]|(?=[.!?*-])", perl = TRUE))

eng.reviews <- reactive({
      data <- query()
      data <- as.data.frame(data)
      eng.reviews <- data[,3]
    })

eng.reviews.list <- reactive({
    eng.reviews <- eng.reviews()
    eng.reviews.list <- list()
    for (i in 1:nrow(eng.reviews)) {
      z <- word_extract(tolower(as.character(eng.reviews[i,1])))
      eng.reviews.list[[i]] <- z
    }
  })
```

Can I use in this case reactive? Next I create VectorSource, Corpus, tm_map, DocumentTermMatrix, dist.matrix.jaccard but I do this in one code snippet which not works in Shiny.

Comment: Hi !
Here is the first google result: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/kmeans-example.html . Code is shown beside the app so you can learn how to reproduce it and furherly pimp it. In your case (160 lines is quite fat), you will need to adapt your script to Shiny K-mean representation. I wish you to succeed ;)

Comment: I saw it but the problem is that I don't know what to do after getting the data. I store the data as reactive so when I create a list of english words should it be a reactive variable?
```eng.reviews.list <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(eng.reviews)) {
  z <- word_extract(tolower(as.character(eng.reviews[i,1])))
  eng.reviews.list[[i]] <- z
}```

Comment: If in the end you just want to have the list available/displayed in Shiny, then you can use a single `reactive`, returning the list in the end. Besides, any object that is reactive is a function, so you need to be careful with the type of operations you do with them.

Comment: At the end I would like to have 2 plots: one with wss.summary and the other one as kmeans. Should I create a function where I enter the data and it processes until wss.summary?